# intersection between conic and cubic

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $ A=V(\alpha)$ a non-singular conic in $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C})$, $V(\delta_1)$ and $V(\delta_2)$ two cubic such that : $D_1$ and $D_2$ meet $A$ tangentially at six distincts points $P_1,...,P_6$ and $D_1$ meets $D_2$ at nine distinct points. then we have a third cubic $B= V(\beta) $ which meets all the $P_i$. 
I would like to understand why $ \alpha | \delta_1\delta_2-\beta^2$

thank you for your answers.

Comment: This is only true up to rescaling, in which case it's obvious. (Scale the polynomials so that their difference vanishes identically on $A$.) I'm voting to migrate.

Comment: Thank you for this answer but i don't really understand...what does that mean "This is only true up to rescaling" ?

Comment: This means that, given $\delta_i$, the coefficient of $\beta$ can be chosen so that ...